# jekyll disable directory listing

Tags: jekyll

I am using a `docker-compose` setup for a jeykll website:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  jekyll:
    image: jekyll/jekyll:latest
    command: jekyll serve --watch
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - ./www:/srv/jekyll
```

The website works, however when I access a directory I receive a directory listing:

[image]

I want the directory listing to redirect to my 404 page, however I cannot find the option to do this.

Can somebody explain how to do this with jekyll?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the jekyll redirect [plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from):

Add this to Gemfile:

```
gem 'jekyll-redirect-from'
```

Then execute:

```
$ bundle
```

Add it to _config.yml:

```
gems:
  - jekyll-redirect-from
```

Create the `/404.html` file or add the following front matter if you already have it:

```
---
title: 404 - Not Found
permalink: /404.html
redirect_from:
- /assets/
---

<p>HTTP 404 Not Found error message</p>
```

**Pay attention to the trailing slash of `/assets/` or it won't work.**

Then each time you access `/assets/` it will redirect to `/404.html`.

Comment: How to easily include sub directories?

Answer (score 2):

Just an update to the previous answer:

For recent versions of Jekyll, the way you have to add the plugin to the `_config.yml` file is as follows:

```
plugins:  
  - jekyll-redirect-from
```

Otherwise it won't work.

Source: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from